# Variance inflation factors in R

Tags: r, memory

I am trying to compute the VIFs from a regression model that has a lot of independent variables (> 100). I am using `vif` from the `car` package to do that.

I always get the error: cannot allocate vector of size 13.8 GB. I realize this is a memory issue, but my PC already has a lot of memory. So the question is, can this function optimized in any way, so it doesn't require so much memory? I am unsure if this is more of a stats or a computational question. And as my dataset is quite large, I am unsure how to represent this case with a MWE. Basically what is needed is a lot of independent variables (e.g. 200+) and one arbitrary dependent variable, with length of each variable around 440 observations. Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran a simulated version of what you did, and it worked fine: it took less than a second to run.  This is 250 explanatory variables and one response, 500 observations.

For entertainment I pasted together a formula for it, but that isn't really necessary.  The vif() were computed easily.

In general, since vif(j) = 1/(1-R^2_j), where R^2_j is the R-squared value when regressing the jth explanatory variable against all the other explanatory variables, computation should take, at most, the time of 250 linear regressions, with 500 observations and 250 explanatory variables, which is very, very fast and not at all memory intensive.

You might need to post your code so we can see what went wrong.

```
> resp <- rnorm(500)
> X <- matrix(nrow=500, ncol=250, rnorm(500*250))
> X <- data.frame(X)
> colnames(X) <- col_names <- paste("x",1:250, sep="")
> formula <- paste(col_names, collapse="+")
> formula <- paste("resp~",formula)
> hold <- lm(formula, data=cbind(resp,X))
> summary(vif(hold))
```

Comment: alright thank you very much, so something went wrong. I double check and will get back to you